# HP Mini upgrade from 12.04 to 13.?? failed

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, laptop, hp

I have an HP Mini 1030NR that was on 12.04 for about a year with no problems.  A couple of days ago I checked for updates and version 13 was available to upgrade so I selected update.  After it started and asked for root login, I left it to do something else.  I forgot about it, and my daughter unplugged it, and it may not have finished updating before it died.  Now it is not working properly.  It seemed fine at first, but it is not detecting the wifi chip, the setting screen opens but is blank, and it no longer asks for a password when it boots. Can I try to install version 13 again or should I go back to 12.04?

Comment: You should go for 14.04 or 12.04. 13.X is unsupported now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and see if it continues the upgrade from where it left off if you can get to a terminal. Since you have no wifi see if you can find ethernet.

Comment: That did the trick!  It was actually 14.04 that was installing.  It is all good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### BACKGROUND:

For the **HP Mini 110 or 210 series** there are various issues (with 12.10, 13.04, or 13.10) with the graphics chipset and quality of the drivers available.

I no longer have a 110 series (I assume you have a **110-1030NR**) to test, but the 210 series works well with **14.04 LTS** (32-bit).

---

### **RECOMMENDATION:**

*If you have your data backed up*, you should proceed with a *new* install of **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit)**. You would also be greatly advantaged by upgrading to 2GB RAM.

**NOTE:** *If you still need to recover your data, do that first. Do **NOT** attempt to fix the OS, until you have a backup of all your data.*